# Javascript function not changing HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am having difficulty with this script showing the yes or no permanently. Could anyone tell me why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Project</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Is it prime?</h1>
<hr>
<p>This tool was designed to determine if a number is prime </p>
<form>
    <input type="number" id="Number" name="enterednumber"/>
    <input type="submit" id="theButton" onclick="isitprime(this.form.enterednumber.value)"/>
</form>
<p id="answer"></p>
</body>
<script>
function isitprime(v)
{
var isprime=0;
for(i=2, i<v, i++)
    {
    if(v%i==0)
        isprime=1;
    }
if(isprime==1)
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="No";
else
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="Yes";
}
</script>
</html>
```

Basically I am trying to pass an entered value to my function isitprime() and then have text that says yes or no pop up.

Comment: Where is the `#maybe` element? Why you are nesting the `body` elements? That's invalid markup, each document must have just one `body` element. And `hr` is a void element, i.e. it doesn't have closing tag!

Comment: where is this `maybe` id ?

Comment: Sorry I had been switching between ids to test it out and see what was wrong. Fixed. Obviously I am very new at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I see is that in your script you are looking for an element with an `id` of `"maybe"`. But in your html the place you want the output to appear has an `id` of `"answer"`.

You also don't want to use a `body` element inside another body element. Instead just use a div for your answer like this:

```
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Also in your for loop use ; instead of ,

```
for(i=2; i<v; i++)
```

Comment: Thank you it was the for loop and I didn't realize it.

Comment: Is there a way to make the yes/no permanent and not disappear instantly?

Comment: Are you still using a `<body>` tag to display the yes/no? You need to not do that. There can only be one `<body>` tag on the page. Use a `<div>` instead. The answer below from @mrrogers is likely why your result is disapearing.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect another issue you might be seeing is that the form is submitted which means the page gets refreshed after you've set the yes/no value.  You might could suppress the form submission by returning false after you call your method (or return false from your method).  Like so:

```
<body>
  <h1>Is it prime?</h1>
  <hr>
  <p>This tool was designed to determine if a number is prime </p>
  <form>
    <input type="number" id="Number" name="enterednumber"/>
    <input type="submit" id="theButton" onclick="return isitprime(this.form.enterednumber.value)"/>
  </form>
  <p id="answer"></p>
</body>
<script>
function isitprime(v) {
  var isprime=0;
  for(i=2; i<v; i++) {
    if(v%i==0) {
        isprime=1;
    }
  }
  if(isprime==1) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="No";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="Yes";
  }
  return false; // make sure that the form doesn't get submitted             
}
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could run the `isitprime` function on page load which could take the value from the query string.

Answer (score 0):

yes you just need to return false after the function like this

```
<input type="submit" id="theButton" onclick="isitprime(this.form.enterednumber.value);return false;"/>
```

you have other ways to do it with to form action tag you can read about it more